# Sorting an array in the same order as another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that looks like this:

**Array 1, $ids:**

```
$ids = array('8', '56', '33', '23', ... and so on);
```

**Array 2 (multidimensional as well as associative), $positions:**

```
$positions[0] = array('id' => '56',
                 'latitude' => '45.34234',
                 'longitude' => '34.23942');

$positions[1] = array('id' => '8',
                 'latitude' => '49.34834',
                 'longitude' => '34.93942');

... and so on.
```

Both arrays contains of id's, but the id's aren't in the same order in the different arrays. What I want is the id's (with their latitudes and longitudes) to be in the same order in $positions as they're in $ids.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Use `usort()` where the comparison function compares the positions of the `id` element in `$ids`.

Comment: No, haven't tried it. Don't know how to apply its functionality to this specific context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$new_positions = array();
foreach($ids as $k=>$v){
  foreach($positions as $k1=>$v1){
    if($v == $v1['id']){
       array_push($new_positions, $v1);
       continue;
    }
  }
}

$positions = $new_positions;
print_r($positions);
```

Check here, http://codepad.org/phWxOEC1

Answer (score 1):

**Upd:** I guess I misunderstood. Sorting `$positions` by `$ids` is even easier.

```
usort($positions, "cmp");
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $ids;
    $a_id = array_search($a['id'], $ids);
    $b_id = array_search($b['id'], $ids);
    if ($a_id == $b_id) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_id < $b_id) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

**Old version**  if you need to sort `$ids` by `$positions`

First, you need to remember the sorting of `id` field, since you can't search effectively in associative array like yours.

```
$sort = array();
$positionsCount = count($positions);
for ($i = 0; $i < $positionsCount; $i++)
{
    $sort[ $positions[$i]['id'] ] = $i;
}
```

Then you can search using `usort();`.

```
usort($ids, "cmp");
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $sort;
    if ($sort[$a] == $sort[$b]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($sort[$a] < $sort[$b]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

This code might need testing, but I hope you got the general idea. If it sorts in reverse, change the `-1 : 1` to `1 : -1`.

Comment: You're sorting the wrong array I think. He wants to sort `$positions`, not `$ids`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I already edited. Sorting `$ids` by `$positions` was more interesting, so I guess my brain tricked me into doing that instead :)